# How to add prefix in top element in soap message

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, asmx

The below is my asmx web service

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://test.com/test")]
 [SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
 public class Pilot : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {
    [WebMethod]
    public Attribute[] IsPilotUser(Data Data)
    {
          //logic here
    }

 }

[Serializable()]
public class Data
{
    public string HumanNo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Attribute")]
public class Attribute
{

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Namespace="http://test.com/test")]
      public string Name = "UserResult";

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Namespace="http://test.com/test")]
    public string value
    {
       get;
       set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces();

    public Attribute()
    {
        xmlns.Add("pf", "http://test.com/test");
        xmlns.Add("pf", "http://test.com/test");
    }

}
```

This is the current soap response message getting genarated once client try to cosume it.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <IsPilotUserResponse xmlns="http://test.com/test">
      <IsPilotUserResult>
        <pf:Attribute xmlns:pf="http://test.com/test">
          <pf:Name>UserResult</pf:Name>
          <pf:value>i am value</pf:value>
        </pf:Attribute>
      </IsPilotUserResult>
    </IsPilotUserResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If you notice the top two elements are not having prefix "pf:"

```
<IsPFMPilotUserResponse xmlns="http://test.com/test">
    <IsPFMPilotUserResult>
```

Is there any way i can add this prefix ?

Comment: Why do you think  you need the prefixes? Prefixes don't matter. Only the namespace they refer to matters.

Comment: Also, FYI, your classes don't need to be `[Serializable]`. The XML Serializer which is used by the legacy ASMX services ignores that attribute.

Comment: At consumer side XPath is being used to find out node value in response and somehow it's looking for "pf:" prefix......

Comment: XPATH shouldn't be looking for a prefix. That's a bug.